# How to include one child module service in another child module

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, dependencies, circular-dependency

I am working on a modular Spring MVC Maven project. Here is the design:

```
portal (Parent)
  portal-core (module1)
  portal-activiti (module2)
  portal-service (module3)
  portal-web (module4)
```

My parent `portal` project contains only the POM with common dependencies and all other module information like below:

```
<modules>
    <module>portal-web</module>
    <module>portal-service</module>
    <module>portal-activiti</module>
    <module>portal-core</module>
</modules>
```

Each child module has it's own POM file. I arranged the module dependency  like below:

`portal-web` module has `portal-service` module as dependency. 
`portal-service` module has `portal-activiti` module as dependency.
`portal-activiti` module has `portal-core` module as dependency.

Everything works fine when I run the application fully (from the web module). But when I run JUnit test cases on individual modules I am getting cyclic reference error.

For example under `activiti` module I need some services from `portal-service` module. So if I include `portal-service` as dependency inside `portal-activiti` module it leads to cyclic reference. Because `portal-service` module already have `portal-activiti` as dependency. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: "portal-service module has portal-activiti module as dependency" and "For example under activiti module I need some services from portal-service module. ". The last sentence means you have a dependency from activiti to service as well so yes you get a cyclic dependency. Move the code used in both modules somewhere else (perhaps a new module or core)

Comment: If your tests require other dependencies than the code to compile, this suggests, that the tests are not on the level of unit tests but integration, therefore you should move the tests to a module that has all dependencies, as @PeterLiljenberg suggested.